# What are the views of Gaudiya Vaishnavism on Adi Shankaracharya?

Tags: adi-shankaracharya, gaudiya-vaishnavism

Adi Shankaracharya is believed to be incarnation of Lord Shiva. What are views of Gaudiya Vaishnavism on Adi Shankaracharya?

Comment: They accept him as Shiva but incarnated to delude people

Answer (score 6):

According to Sri Chaitanya Charitamrita, Sri Chaitanyadeva quoted the slokas of Padma-Purana ( CC 2/6/162-164)

> Sri Krishna's order to Shiva : " Swaagamaih kalpitastawamcha janaan madbimukhaan kuru" -- make peole distarcted from me by creating your own inaginary paths.
>
> Shiva's statement in Padma-Purana to Devi : Mayavaadam asat shaastram prachchannam baudhdham uchchyate/ Maya eva bihitam devi kalau brahmana-murtina// -- Mayavaad is a false doctrine which is buddhism in disguise. I have preached this in Kaliyuga taking a brahmin form."

The above provides the view of the Gaudiya Vaishnavas on Adi Sankaracharya as mentioned in the Sri Sri Chaitanya Charitamrita.

Answer (score 2):

Gaudiya Vaishnavas accept Adi Shankara to be an incarnation of Shiva. However, they believe that like Buddha, Adi Shankara was born to deviate the people in Kali-Yuga from the path of the Vedas.

This is what Jiva Goswami states in his "Sri Tattva Sandarbha" regarding Adi Shankara:

> *atha yad eva kaivalyam apy atikramya bhakti-sukha-vyaharadi-lingena-nija
>   matasyapy upari viraj amanartham matva yad apauruseyam vedanta-vyakhyanam
>   bhayad acalayataiva sankaravatarataya prasiddhena vaksyamana-sva-gopanadi
>   hetuka-bhagavad-ajna-pravartitadvaya-vadenapi etan-matra-varnita-visva-rupa-
>   darsana-krta-vrajesvari-vismaya-sri vraja-kumari-vasana-cauryadikam
>   govindastakadau varnayata tata-sthi-bhuya nija-vacah-saphalyaya sprstam iti.*
>
> **Sankaracarya, known to be an incarnation of Lord Sankara**,
>   considered the message of Srimad-Bhagavatam far superior to his own conception
>   of merging with the Supreme, in as much as it reveals the pleasure pastimes of pure
>   devotion and other special truths. **Because the Personality of Godhead wanted to
>   hide Himself and accomplish other purposes, Sankaracarya on His order
>   promulgated the philosophy of Oneness**, which we will discuss later on.
>   Nonetheless Sankaracarya was anxious not to disturb the Bhagavatam, the original authorless commentary on the Vedanta. By depicting in his Govindastaka and
>   other works events described only by the Bhagavatam — such as the Queen of
>   Vraja's amazement at seeing the total form of the universe and Krsna's stealing the
>   clothes of the unmarried girls of Vraja — he kept himself at a respectful distance and
>   merely touched the Bhagavatam to assure the success of his own words. (**Sri Tattva Sandarbha 23.3**)

Comment: what did Sripad Jiva Goswami say about the 11thncanto of Srimad-Bhagavatam where Hari is referred to as Nirguna and He Himself advised Jnanamarga?

Comment: @Partha Can you tell me the exact verse actually?

Comment: @Partha Is it Srimad Bhagavatam 11.25.27?

Comment: The sloka that reads: Harir hi nirguno sakshad?

Comment: @Partha I'll check

Comment: @Partha i think as you pointed translations are wrong. Even in Gita, Avyakta akshara, Param Purusha is wrongly translated as personality of Godhead....

Comment: @Partha I got your verse. It's actually in the tenth canto.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury okay, how is it explained?

Comment: @AkshayS yes thats true with the ISKCON gita :D

Comment: @Partha It seems Gaudiya Vaishnavas would interpret it to explain that Hari is untouched/not influenced by the three gunas and hence Nirguna. Now, if you want to know what Jiva Goswami says, check this  book in Sanskrit: https://archive.org/details/SrimadBhagavatamCanto10withMultipleSanskritCommentaries/page/n7176 (I can't read Sanskrit so I can't tell you myself)

Comment: @Surya Kanta Bose Chowdhury thnx so mch